# How to get image url after click on a image in a image list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of image in index file as below:

```
<div id="image-list"
    <ul>
        <li data-id='1'>
            <img src='image/001.jpg' alt=''>
        </li>
        <li data-id='2'>
            <img src='image/002.jpg' alt=''>
        </li>
        <li data-id='3'>
            <img src='image/003.jpg' alt=''>
        </li>
                   
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I made an click event for image list:

```
document.getElementById("image-list").addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImage == 'url("image/001.jpg")'){
        console.log("I clicked in the image 001");
    }
    if(document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImage == 'url("image/002.jpg")'){
        console.log("I clicked in the image 002");
    }
    if(document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundImage == 'url("image/003.jpg")'){
        console.log("I clicked in the image 003");
    }
});
```

But I have issue load wrong url. When I am in image 001 and click on image 002, the function above show log "I clicked in the image 001" instead of "I clicked in the image 002" as I expect.

Anyone can help me give a right function that when I click on image 002, the console log print "I clicked in the image 002" as I expect.
Thanks.

Comment: Not related to the issue, but you have a typo in your HTML `<div id="image-list"` is missing the end of the tag. Also, what is this element with ID `background` that you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should target all the images then loop through them and attach the event. Inside the event handler function get the `src` attribute and match that.

**Demo:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#image-list ul > li > img").forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var src = this.getAttribute('src');
      if(src == "image/001.jpg"){
          console.log("I clicked in the image 001");
      }
      else if(src == "image/002.jpg"){
          console.log("I clicked in the image 002");
      }
      else if(src == "image/003.jpg"){
          console.log("I clicked in the image 003");
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="image-list">
    <ul>
        <li data-id='1'>
            <img src='image/001.jpg' alt='11'>
        </li>
        <li data-id='2'>
            <img src='image/002.jpg' alt='22'>
        </li>
        <li data-id='3'>
            <img src='image/003.jpg' alt='33'>
        </li>
                   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much. This code resolve my problem.

Comment: @Einz, you are most welcome:)